# Image change using setInterval in React/Gatsby with Graphql and Gatsby Image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby, gatsby-image

I'm trying to create an Image changing component in Gatsby/React from the results on a Graphql query.
I am stuck and don't know what to do inside that setInterval function. Any Help appreciated. Thanks

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from "gatsby";
import Img from "gatsby-image";

function ImgRotator() {
   const imageData = useStaticQuery(graphql`
      query {
         allFile(filter: { extension: { regex: "/(jpg)|(jpeg)|(png)/" }, relativeDirectory: { eq: "rotator" } }) {
            edges {
               node {
                  id
                  childImageSharp {
                     fluid(maxWidth: 2880) {
                        ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   `);

   const allImages = imageData.allFile.edges;
   const [images] = useState(allImages);
   const [displayImage, setDisplayImage] = useState(imageData.allFile.edges[0].node.childImageSharp.fluid);


   useEffect(() => {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {

         // Help! Don't know what to do here

      }, 1000);
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
   }, [displayImage]);

   return <Img fluid={displayImage} alt="" loading="eager" />;
}

export default ImgRotator;
```

Comment: it's not hard to imagine that you need a counter/index (state) and should be increased in interval, reseted on max ... basic react state action ... autoincreasing counter examples

Answer (score 1):

One workaround that may work for you is:

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from "gatsby";
    import Img from "gatsby-image";
    
    function ImgRotator() {
       const imageData = useStaticQuery(graphql`
          query {
             allFile(filter: { extension: { regex: "/(jpg)|(jpeg)|(png)/" }, relativeDirectory: { eq: "rotator" } }) {
                edges {
                   node {
                      id
                      childImageSharp {
                         fluid(maxWidth: 2880) {
                            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
                         }
                      }
                   }
                }
             }
          }
       `);
    
       const allImages = imageData.allFile.edges;
       const [currentImage, setCurrentImage]=useState({});
       const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex]=useState(0);
    
    
       useEffect(() => {
          const interval = setInterval(() => {
                 
            setCurrentImage(allImages[currentIndex].node.childImageSharp.fluid)
             setCurrentIndex(currentIndex++)
                  
          }, 1000);
          return () => clearInterval(interval);
       }, [currentIndex]);
    
       return <Img fluid={currentImage} alt="" loading="eager" />;
    }
    
    export default ImgRotator;
```

Summarizing, you initially set two states:

```
   const [currentImage, setCurrentImage]=useState({});
   const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex]=useState(0);
```

Quite self-explanatory: `currentImage` will store your displayed image and `currentIndex` the index in the array of that image.

In your `useEffect` (triggered once the `currentIndex` changes) you've defined an interval where it looks for the `currentIndex` in `allImages` and sets the `currentImage` using that index. Each second the function is being triggered again so it will update the system.

Your `gatsby-image` will show the `currentImage` based on that interval:

```
   return <Img fluid={currentImage} alt="" loading="eager" />;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ferran. Your solution works.
Only one problem in my setup: The images are flashing between changes like they get unmounted and remounted
Is there a way to get a a smooth change with no gaps between images?

Comment: @FerranBuireu not in 'pure react' ... old node is just removed, no fadeOut/slideOut possible ... css can only affect appearing elements ... you have to use some react animation lib ... or try to render 2 (prev+current) images with keys